# Can't bind to 'dimensionValidator' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive which is used in shared component.Directive takes an input which is of type string. when I use it in the template I get the error that it isn't a known property of input. As the directive is  shared  I declared it in the shared module.Can anyone let me know how to resolve this issue.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dimensionValidator]',
  providers: [
    { multi: true, useExisting: forwardRef(() => DimensionValidator), provide: NG_VALIDATORS }
  ]
})
export class DimensionValidator implements Validator {
 @Input('dimensionValidator') selectedCountryCode: string;
  public packageTypeEnum = PackageDetailsEnums;
  isInternational: boolean;
  constructor() {
  }

  validate(formController: AbstractControl) {
    return Object.assign(
      this._validateDimensions(formController)
    )
  }


  private _validateDimensions (formController: AbstractControl) {
    if (formController.touched || formController.dirty) {
      //Check if the destination address is international

        if (this.selectedCountryCode == GlobalConstants.COUNTRYCODE.CANADA || this.selectedCountryCode == GlobalConstants.COUNTRYCODE.USA) {
          this.isInternational = false;
        } else {
          this.isInternational = true;
        }
      if (formController.parent.get('units').value == this.packageTypeEnum.metric) {  // If the selected unit is mertic
        // Domestic/USA valid value ( 0.01 - 200 / cm) --- International valid value ( 0.01 - 150 / cm)
        if ((this.isInternational ? Number(formController.value) >=  GlobalConstants.DIRECTIVES.FIELD_MAXVAL_MET_INT : Number(formController.value) >=  GlobalConstants.DIRECTIVES.FIELD_MAXVAL_MET) || Number(formController.value) < GlobalConstants.DIRECTIVES.INPUT_FIELD_MIN_VAL) {
            return {invalidValue: true};
        } else { // Check Girth ( Length + (width + height) * 2) if the values are valid
          return this.calculateGirthForValidValues(formController, GlobalConstants.DIRECTIVES.MAX_GIRTH_MET);
        }
      } else { // selected unit is imperial
        // Domestic/USA valid value ( 0.01-78.7 inch) --- International valid value ( 0.01 - 59 inch)
        if ((this.isInternational ? Number(formController.value) >=  GlobalConstants.DIRECTIVES.FIELD_MAXVAL_IMP_INT : Number(formController.value) >=  GlobalConstants.DIRECTIVES.FIELD_MAXVAL_IMP) || Number(formController.value) < GlobalConstants.DIRECTIVES.INPUT_FIELD_MIN_VAL) {
          return {invalidValue: true};
        } else { // Check Girth ( Length + (width + height) * 2) if the values are valid
          return this.calculateGirthForValidValues(formController, GlobalConstants.DIRECTIVES.MAX_GIRTH_IMP);
        }
      }
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  }
}
```

This is the HTML template

```
<input type="text" id="boxHeight" [dimensionValidator]="selectedCountryCode"/>
```